# Using WindowFromPoint P/Invoke to get handle of browser tab

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I'm writing a C# application that interacts with a web browser game (not for malicious purposes, just for the challenge of automation) and have the interaction working by moving the mouse, clicking and then moving the mouse back to the previous point.

What I am trying to do now is do the click on the point without moving the cursor, so that moving the mouse while it is running won't cause misclicks. I found the WindowFromPoint and SendMessage hooks that I can use to click on the position, and in my testing I was able to get this combination to work. But when trying to get this combination of hooks to work on my Chrome web browser where the game is located it won't make the click.

I'm assuming that the incorrect handle is being gathered, seeing as chrome is so complex. But the way I figured it would work is the WindowFromPoint would provide me with the handle for the current browser tab that is open, thus the SendMessage would be able to perform the click where I want.

Here is the code that I am using, start and end are both Point objects that are located at the position where I want to click:

```
IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(start);
if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
    SendMessage(hWnd, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr hWnd2 = WindowFromPoint(end);
    SendMessage(hWnd2, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Is there anything different I should be doing in order to perform a click on the game in the browser tab?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be that simple:

The BM_CLICK message presumes the owner of the window handler handles BM_CLICK messages. This is a "higher level" message which gets generated when "lower level" messages (such as mouse down/up, keyboard press, etc.) are processed.
In the case of Windows standard controls such as buttons this happens under the scenes, but I don't believe the browser (or flash plugin, or whatever) uses standard Win32 controls to render its pages so it may or may not handle mouse clicks/keyboard presses and issue BM_CLICK events.

There's a wonderful tool in most versions of Visual Studio (even some C++ express ones) to aid you in your pursuit called Spy++.
This tool allows you "walk" the window handle structure, select windows (with the somewhat bizarre finder tool in Spy->Log Messages)  and log events processed by specific windows.

According to this tool pressing the "C#" tag button in your question in Chrome does not own a handle and looking at the events on the render control it no BM_CLICK events are created.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer.

Thanks for pointing me to the Spy++ tool. Using it I can see that most non-OS windows handle very few messages.

I guess I will continue my hunt for a solution.